# How to set werl.exe window size and position in the .erlang configuration file?

Tags: erlang, position, window, werl.exe

Does anyone know if there is anyway to set the windows size and position for werl.exe in the .erlang config file? Or set it to keep the position from last time?

I have already configured the starting directory and found a cool IO effect. So my current file looks like this:

```
io:format("C:/Program Files/erl8.0/bin/.erlang\n").
io:format(" ______      _                   \n").
io:format("|  ____|    | |                  \n").
io:format("| |__   _ __| | __ _ _ __   __ _ \n").
io:format("|  __| | '__| |/ _` | '_ \\ / _` |\n").
io:format("| |____| |  | | (_| | | | | (_| |\n").
io:format("|______|_|  |_|\\__,_|_| |_|\\__, |\n").
io:format("                            __/ |\n").
io:format("                           |___/ \n\n").
shell_default:cd("C:/MyDir").
```

Found nothing on google about this, so I'm hoping someone in here knows!

Thanks in advance!